# Strange sump pump install by plumber

Tags: plumbing, sump-pump

I'm thinking about finishing my basement but at the bottom of my stairs the plumber installed a very strange setup for my sump pump.  See attached picture.

[image]

Ive never seen this before so I wanted to know if I could shorten this.
My neighborhood is on a hill/rise and the house is about in the middle. There's a collection pond at the bottom.

Edit: the PVC pipe is connected to the storm drain on the left and to the sump pump in the pit on the right.  I want to make this setup smaller by shortening the black pvc pipe from the ceiling to the floor.  I don't even know why this setup is necessary since it's connected to a storm drain. This is in my basement which is underground.

Comment: Shorten what? I'm not entirely clear what you're asking.

Comment: What's the pipe to the left of the sump? Where do the two pipes go? And, per @Comintern, what's the question?

Comment: This pipe is directly in the way of the stairs so I want to shorten it all the way to the ground level and build a box over the remaining 6 inches.  The pipe makes a huge upside down U and connects to the storm drain and the sump pump

Comment: Storm drain or sewer?  There's a huge difference - around here you can't run a sump pump into the sewer line at all.  If it *is* the sewer, it may be set up that way to try and prevent the sump pump from blasting raw sewage up through all of the drains in the house.

Comment: The pipe on the left looks to be connected to a pump on top of the cement, they are usually in a pit because the pump needs a few inches of water to work. If that is the case I think it won't work until until everything down there is soaked. I don't see any water marks on the walls so is it really needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be a back flow-prevention measure, for flash flooding rains. I think your only good, but expensive ($1000), option would be to replace this setup with a Back-Flow Prevention Valve or Check Valve. Call the Builder or get a qualified Plumber...have them checkout your Water Supply Line too, that thing looks 100-years old. Otherwise, turn that corner into a closet or faux bookshelf.

Comment: Thanks for your input! I think your 100% right about the back flow from the storm drain.. It does have a small check valve close to the sump pump.  Funny enough this install is only 4 years old!

Comment: No problem at all. Plumbers don't do extra work or waste materials.